# Help solving complicated polynomial equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following two equations, but I am having troubles doing so.

Equation 1 :

```
eq1[n_] := 
  2.21355*10^(-16)/((1 - n)^2)*(1024/5 + 3*7133.17 n^2) - 
   4.42709*10^(-16)/((1 - n)^3)*(1024/5*n + 7133.17 n^3) ;
Solve[eq1[n] == 0, n]
```

If I can find an "n", I would then plug it into the following equation and solve for V.

```
eq2[n_] := 1024/5*n + 7133.17 n^3 - 
  0.06287*V^2*2.21355*10^(-16)/((1 - n)^2);

Solve[eq2[nFound] == 0, V]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, I am not very sure what you want to ask. Maybe you want to substitute the solution of the first equation into the second equation? Then you can do this.

```
eq1[n_] := 
  2.21355*10^(-16)/((1 - n)^2)*(1024/5 + 3*7133.17 n^2) - 
   4.42709*10^(-16)/((1 - n)^3)*(1024/5*n + 7133.17 n^3);
ansList = Values@Solve[eq1[n] == 0, n]

eq2[n_] := 
  1024/5*n + 7133.17 n^3 - 0.06287*V^2*2.21355*10^(-16)/((1 - n)^2);

Solve[eq2[#] == 0, V] & /@ ansList
```

You also can use the following code to get the value of `n`.

```
sol=Solve[eq1[n] == 0, n]
nList=n/.sol
```

That's all. Please enjoy the fun of Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks ! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Never thought about using the `Values` function in this context. Thanks for the new idea!

Answer (score 3):

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) can handle simultaneous equations. `Solve` is an exact solver so use [`Rationalze`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalze.html) to provide exact numbers as input. `Solve` will work without doing this but will provide a warning that it did it internally. Or use [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html).

```
eq1[n_] := 
  Evaluate[2.21355*10^(-16)/((1 - n)^2)*(1024/5 + 3*7133.17 n^2) - 
      4.42709*10^(-16)/((1 - n)^3)*(1024/5*n + 7133.17 n^3) // 
     Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify];

eq2[n_] := Evaluate[1024/5*n + 7133.17 n^3 - 
 0.06287*V^2*2.21355*10^(-16)/((1 - n)^2) // Rationalize[#, 0] &];

Solve[{eq1[n] == 0, eq2[n] == 0}, {n, V}] // N

(* {{n -> 0.00634203 + 0.0986751 I, 
  V -> -7.58581*10^8 - 6.22509*10^8 I}, {n -> 0.00634203 + 0.0986751 I, 
  V -> 7.58581*10^8 + 6.22509*10^8 I}, {n -> 0.00634203 - 0.0986751 I, 
  V -> 7.58581*10^8 - 6.22509*10^8 I}, {n -> 0.00634203 - 0.0986751 I, 
  V -> -7.58581*10^8 + 6.22509*10^8 I}, {n -> 0.587316, 
  V -> -4.37685*10^9}, {n -> 0.587316, V -> 4.37685*10^9}} *)
```

For real solutions

```
Solve[{eq1[n] == 0, eq2[n] == 0}, {n, V}, Reals] // N

(* {{n -> 0.587316, V -> -4.37685*10^9}, {n -> 0.587316, V -> 4.37685*10^9}} *)
```

For real, positive solutions

```
Solve[{eq1[n] == 0, eq2[n] == 0, V > 0}, {n, V}] // N

(* {{n -> 0.587316, V -> 4.37685*10^9}} *)
```

Comment: This is a great answer ! Thank you very much !

Comment: How would you do it with Rationalize ?

Comment: Look at the definition of `eq1` above. At the end you will see that `Rationalize` and `Simplify` are used. Since `SetDelayed ( := )` is used in the definition rather than `Set ( = )`, `Evaluate` is used to have these evaluated at the time of definition rather than for each use of the function `eq1`. Similarly for `eq2` except `Simplify` wasn't needed. Read the documentation for each of these functions.